# React + Redux - Render app based on access level

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I have built an API and now i am building a react app to go with it. The app will have different access level e.g user and admin. The problem i have at the moment is that The whole react app is rendered and sent to the client. So even though the routes are protected on the server. A user could potentially access the admin intended JavaScript on the client.

I'm trying to figure out how i can have a user log in and from that decide what to JavaScript to serve. After 2 days looking into this I am still stuck. A lot of articles seem to suggest making the App isomorphic (render the JS server side) but is there no other way of doing this. The solution we are leaning towards at the moment is having different builds. A build that just contains the JavaScript for the login. Then after auth we use that to decide if to load the user build or the admin build. This is going to mean repetition and i dont really like this method.. but its the only way i can think of at the moment.

My question is.. what is the best way to handle this in react? Also can react load components on the fly? so we could have the app just contain the login JavaScript and when Auth passes we send details on what components the user should have access to and then just load theses

Comment: Do you need something more sophisticated than choosing one root component over another when the user is logged in?

Comment: Sorry but I'm going to be honest and say I don't really understand what you mean. I'm new to react (plus I'm a back end developer) most of the app has already been built by someone else and I've been tasked with making sure that only the JavaScript that relates to the ROLE of the logged in user is rendered and served. Thinking i should do some more research on react and redux in general.

Comment: Given a flag the identifies the user as logged in, you can decide which Components to render. Imagine a simple component like: `const MainView = props => props.isLoggedIn ? <LoggedInView /> : <StandardView />`

Comment: I think i understand what you mean. But is this not just changing the view within the app on the client side. As in the javascript for both views are still in the main build of the app but what isn't required is hidden(not rendered)? For eaxmple if the user was to inspect and access the bundle.js, they could locate the component code for the admin stuff. or even just change there role on the client side to open up access to these other components? they wont be able to access the API routes that these components need but can still see the view stuff.

Comment: In that case you might want a separate bundle for your admin section. You can build that so that you share all of the standard components and have some that only appear in  your admin bundle once the user is signed in. Pretty much a separate app for admin that uses the same base components.

Comment: Yeah thanks for your help. This is what i was thinking, i just thought there might be another way but you have kind of confirmed what i was thinking. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me :)